# Aligning an item to the end of a responsive card, with vertical centering

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to align an item, in this case a Font Awesome icon, to the end of a responsively sized card (width wise). I am struggling to get this to work. Here is my html for my card:

```
<div class="card mt-4 mycard">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Description of card, chevron should be at the end of the card, vertically centred even when card width increases</p>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-3x align-self-center"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see the chevron does not remain at the end of the card. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Here is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you want it to be like?

Comment: Done. The chevron should remain at the end of the card, even when the size of the card changes width wise. (It's responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way I think to do this is like this:

a bit change on HTML structure, just pulled the icon outside the car-body div

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom: 3rem; margin-top: 1rem;">Align right in Bootstrap 4</h2>
    <div class="card mt-4 mycard">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Description of card, chevron should be at the end of the card, vertically centred even when card width Description of card, chevron should be at the end of the card, vertically centred even when card width increases</p>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-3x align-self-center"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    i {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 20px;
        transform: translate(0,-50%);
    }
    .card-body {
        padding-right: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. The align-self-center & mycard are also can be removed from the above as they are not needed. Is there a way of doing this that supports <IE10?

Comment: This is great :) you are welcome. and sure you can by compiling your css code using this tool [auto prefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: Thank you- I'm a bit confused- what's this autoprefixer thing doing exactly, and how would it change transform: translate(0,-50%); into something IE supports?

Comment: no problem, auto prefixer will convert your css code and add proper prefix that works on different browsers that don't support some properties (like transform, flex and grid...etc)

Comment: That's really cool, I didn't know about it so thank you. I will try and use it in the future- is there an easy way to test IE without a Virtual Machine?

Comment: good for you :) and sorry I don't know anything like that, sorry. good luck

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE!

Add absolute positioning, set top to 50% and transform Y to -50% to account for height of icon

```css
.mycard {
  flex-direction: row!important;
}


/*this attempted solution does not seem to work*/

.chevron {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: transformY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 3rem; margin-top: 1rem;">Align right in Bootstrap 4</h2>
  <div class="card mt-4 mycard">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Description of card, chevron should be at the end of the card, vertically centred even when card width increases</p>
        <i class="fas chevron fa-chevron-right fa-3x align-self-center"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added this to the codepen and unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, see here: https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/wvKqyBN The chevron is not at the end of the card, not in the centre vertically.

Comment: I see, I didnt realise that. I think you  will need to give it absolute position with right: 0, position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);

Comment: remove the p tag

Comment: Yep, that was it- guy above got it just before you did, thank you though.

Comment: Glad all sorted

Answer (score 0):

You can push it to the end using `margin-left: 100%`:

```css
.mycard {
  flex-direction: row!important;
}

.fa-chevron-right {
  margin-left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <h2 style="margin-bottom: 3rem; margin-top: 1rem;">Align right in Bootstrap 4</h2>
  <div class="card mt-4 mycard">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Description of card, chevron should be at the end of the card, vertically centred even when card width increases</p>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-3x align-self-center"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```