# How can I align content and arrow both in same line on a div?

Tags: css

The CSS `display:` works for the text elements, but it is not doing anything for `<i>` element. I am able to move it with `float: right` which is where I need it to be on my div but then the padding is off and a headache to deal with! Any feedback would be greatly appreciated :) 
Part of my code is below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/37471687aa.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <nav>
        <div class="arrow-left">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-inverse fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <section class="restaurant-list">
        <div class="location">
          <div class="content">
            <h1>Bakalaki Greek Taverna</h1>
            <h3>Seng Poh Road 3, Singapore</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="arrow">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 420px;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.restaurant-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.location {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: .02px  solid #333;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.location:hover {
  background-color: #888;
}

.content {
 display:block;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;

}

.content h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.arrow  {
display: inline-block;
}
```

I feel like I am missing some detail here when I use `display: inline-block` on element arrow. I know the .arrow works because `float: right;` works for it. I don't know what I am missing here. I need the text to be on left of div and the arrow to be on the right.

Comment: Do you want second arrow to the right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511766/aligning-an-item-to-the-end-of-a-responsive-card-with-vertical-centring-bootst/61512097?noredirect=1#comment108811493_61512097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, this will solve your problem :

Css:

```
.location {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: .02px  solid #333;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  /* You can solve the problem with Display flex. */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following codes?
What I added are:

1. Add `float: left;` in the css class `.content`;
2. Add `float: right;` in the css class `.arrow`;

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 420px;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.restaurant-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.location {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: .02px  solid #333;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.location:hover {
  background-color: #888;
}

.content {
 float: left;
 display:block;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;

}

.content h3 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.arrow  {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/37471687aa.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <nav>
        <div class="arrow-left">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-inverse fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <section class="restaurant-list">
        <div class="location">
          <div class="content">
            <h1>Bakalaki Greek Taverna</h1>
            <h3>Seng Poh Road 3, Singapore</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="arrow">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```